# Mathing all branch of a ltree in postgres

Tags: postgresql, ltree

I have a tree like this:

```
               Country
                  |
                State
              ____|____
             /         \
          City_1       City_2
      ______|______
     /             \
Neighborhood_1     Neighborhood_2
```

In my database I have this records:

```
| path                               |
|------------------------------------|
| Country                            |
| Country.State                      |
| Country.State.City1                |
| Country.State.City2                |
| Country.State.City1.Neighborhood_1 |
| Country.State.City1.Neighborhood_2 |
```

I want to search from a path, and get all the records for any node mathing that path, excluding what is not in the matched branch, like this:

```
| path                               |
|------------------------------------|
| Country                            |
| Country.State                      |
| Country.State.City1                |
| Country.State.City1.Neighborhood_1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

By using the operator `@>`:

```
select * from table where path @> Country.State.City1.Neighborhood_1
```

[Official `ltree` Doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ltree.html)